# How to get count of letter occurrence in variable column per subject [R]

Tags: r, string, character

After searching for an answer on SO, I struck out in finding how to apply solutions to my problem specifically.

**Brief Summary of the Problem:**
I have a very long data set with several observations *per subject/ID*. The column of interest has multiple letters signifying the number of that type of biological phenomenon in the subject.

- For example: if subject 12345 has 'U U U S' I would like to have a separate column/variable spit out not just the count of "U's" but do this ***per subject***; each line with 12345 after would have the number 3 in that column and would ignore the "S's"

**What I have tried:**

- the dplyr method of counting and aggregating - data got real funky real quick
- hand coding in excel, only to find thousands of rows...

**Code and Reproducible sample:**

Here's what the data should look like roughly ('out' variable is my desired count):

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
                  raw = c('U U U S', 'U S U S', 'U S U', 'U', 'S U', 'UU'),
                  out= c(3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2))
```

This problem comes up alot in my job so it would be great to find a repeatable programmatic solution!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify what exactly being counted? Is "U" being counted?

Comment: I'm unclear on your desired output. For example ID 4 only has one row that says "screening". Why do they have an output of 2? And thy does subject 1 have a value of 1 when they have the string "S U U" which has two Us? Also since subject 2 has the value of "2" for out for both rows, does that mean you always want to keep the max number of occurrences per subject?

Comment: is the `out` column your expected output?

Comment: @AlexanderChristensen yes, I would like to only count the "U" occurrences (not case-sensitive)

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for this note, the data should be more accurate now - but the output should be a column with the counts of U per subject ID it corresponds to: if UUUS, the new count should have 3 for every time this matching ID comes up.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't work - only `4` strings in `raw`, but `ID` and `out` are `length = 6`.

Comment: @DanAdams should work now as planned, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're just trying to detect the number of occurrences of the letter `u` within each row of `raw` and find the maximum of that per `ID`. The `u_cnt` column in this output matches the `out` you supplied so I think this will get you what you need.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
                  raw = c('U U U S', 'U S U S', 'U S U', 'U', 'S U', 'UU'),
                  out= c(3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2))

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(u_cnt = max(str_count(raw, fixed("u", ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      ID raw       out u_cnt
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1 U U U S     3     3
#> 2     2 U S U S     2     2
#> 3     2 U S U       2     2
#> 4     3 U           1     1
#> 5     3 S U         1     1
#> 6     4 UU          2     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `u_cnt`.
i `u_cnt = str_count(raw, fixed("u", ignore_case = TRUE))`.
x argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)```  @danadams, this resulted from my attempt

Comment: If your actual data is of the same type as the sample you shared it will work. Can you share `str(df)` in the question to verify? You might need to just do something like `mutate(raw = as.character(raw))`, although I can't imagine what other data type it would be.